# pymongo : unhashable type: 'dict' error on $setOnInsert

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert/Update documents to my mongodb collection from python code, I want to check if the ticket-id exist in the collection, if exists then i want to update only modification column, else if the ticket-id doesn't exist, i want to insert a new record with the 'newdata', based on below code,

```
            newdata = {'Assigned To Group' : d['Assigned To Group'],
                       'Modification Date' : d['Modification Date'],
                       'Creation Date' : d['Creation Date'],
                       'SPSyncRequired' : 'Yes'}
            db_cm.update({'Ticket-ID' : d['Ticket-ID']},
                         {
                             {
                                 "$set":
                                 {
                                     'Modification Date' : d['Modification Date']
                                }
                            },
                         {
                             "$setOnInsert" : newdata
                             }
                        }, multi = True, upsert = True)
```

I am facing (unhashable type: 'dict') this error , anyone help me where am i going wrong

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell because we don't know what `db_cm` is (please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example), but I suspect you are trying to use a dictionary as a dictionary key. Any dictionary key must be hashable. A dictionary is not hashable.

Comment: db_cm is my db and collection name, its "db.tablehistory.update"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve